# Set specific row from database as default value for drop down menu

Tags: javascript, database, drop-down-menu, default

this is my first time asking for help and I know very little about coding. This was mostly done for me.

On a product page I have two drop down menus. One with a version select and one with a size select. Version selection determines what sizes are offered.

When the page loads the first record set for the respective product is used as initially selected.

```
<body onload="WA_FilterAndPopulateSubList(rssize_WAJA,MM_findObj('SelectVersion'),MM_findObj('SelectSize'),0,0,false,': '); showprice()">
```

This is the function for showprice witch is also called in the drop menu, because whenever the user makes a selection, three values on the page switch,prize, pzn and item number (no pzn in English):

```
function showprice() {
var fm = document.segufix_1_ATC_<?php echo $row_DetailRS1["product_id"]; ?>;
var selectedversion = fm.SelectVersion.options[document.segufix_1_ATC_<?php echo $row_DetailRS1["product_id"]; ?>.SelectVersion.selectedIndex].text;
var selectedsize = fm.SelectSize.options[document.segufix_1_ATC_<?php echo $row_DetailRS1["product_id"]; ?>.SelectSize.selectedIndex].text;
var versionset = fm.SelectVersion.value;
var sizeset = fm.SelectSize.value;
var priceset = js_array[(sizeset+0+versionset)].toFixed(2);
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['languageID']) && (!($_SESSION['languageID'] == "2" || $_SESSION['languageID'] == "4"))) {  ?>
priceset = priceset.replace(".", ","); 
<?php } ?>
var pznset = js_array2[(sizeset+0+versionset)];
var itemnolongset = js_array3[(sizeset+0+versionset)];

document.getElementById('pricelabel').innerHTML=' € '+priceset;
document.getElementById('pznlabel').innerHTML=pznset;
document.getElementById('itemnolonglabel').innerHTML=itemnolongset;

}
```

This is the second select menu (size menu):

```
<select class="<?php echo $tmpElementClassSize; ?> name="SelectSize" id="SelectSize" onchange="showprice()">
                  <?php
do {  
?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $row_rssizedefault['size_id']?>"<?php if (!(strcmp($row_rssizedefault['size_id'], $row_rssize['size']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>><?php echo $row_rssizedefault['size']?></option>
                  <?php
} while ($row_rssizedefault = mysql_fetch_assoc($rssizedefault));
$rows = mysql_num_rows($rssizedefault);
if($rows > 0) {
  mysql_data_seek($rssizedefault, 0);
  $row_rssizedefault = mysql_fetch_assoc($rssizedefault);
}
?>
                </select>
```

I would like for the size menu to initially select size "M".

Replacing this line:

```
<?php if (!(strcmp($row_rssizedefault['size_id'], $row_rssize['size']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>
```

with this line:

```
<?php echo $row_rssizedefault['size_id']?>"<?php if ($row_rssizedefault['size_id']=='4' ?>
```

initially selects size "M", but the prize is not displayed correctly (though it will put the  product in the cart with the correct prize). For "M" to display I also have to delete the onload in the body tag. Otherwise it will show "M" for a split second and then change to "XS" (the first record).

Is it possible to select a default from the database in the javascript function?

Sorry for the long post. This is the link to one of the product pages: http://www.segufixshop.eu/detail_en.php?recordID=13

Answer (score 0):

Having the body tag like this:

```
<body onload="showprice()">
```

and the select attribute like this:

```
<?php if ($row_rssizedefault['size_id']=='4') {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>
```

preselects size "M" in the size menu, but then the size menu is populated with all size choices and not size choices relevant to the version.

Is it possible to change the body tag, so that the size menu will populate according to the version menu without resetting the size to "XS"?

```
<body onload="WA_FilterAndPopulateSubList(rssize_WAJA,MM_findObj('SelectVersion'),MM_findObj('SelectSize'),0,0,false,': '); showprice()">
```